# как написать запрос к нескольким значениям в одном столбце

Tags: mysql, sql

Простой вопрос. Как одним запросом вытащить значения нескольких ячеек по id(или еще по-чему).
Например в таблице

```
    id | name
    -------------
     1 | Вася
     2 | Серёжа
     3 | Петя 
     4 | Федя
```

Вытащить только Федю и Серёжу одним запросом.
Первое что хочется написать

```
   SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 2 AND id = 4
```

Но логически это конечно бред =)
Подскажите как правильно составить такой запрос.

Comment: Вариант 1: Вывести тех, чьё имя Федя и Серёжа. Вариант 2: Вывести тех, чьё имя Федя или Серёжа. Выбери правильный...

Comment: @Akina 1 Вариант не работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 2 OR id = 4
```

или

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (2, 4)
```